# How to split a string received via a GSM module (message)

Tags: string

I am doing a motorcycle security system. In this system, I will receive a message from GSM in the form `{password:operation (like start,stop,alarm):time}`.
Example:(9990:start:30)

now i need to split  each term seperately (a=9990,b=start,c=30).help me to solve

Comment: You may need to say how you receive the message or how it's stored.   As is, the question is vague.  Also edit the question and add an explained example, like "{14:C:123}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution is to use [sscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

```
  int password;
  char operation;
  int time;
  char* buf = "{14:C:123}";
  int n = sscanf(buf, "{%d:%c:%d}", &password, &operation, &time);
  Serial.print(F("n="));
  Serial.println(n);
  Serial.print(F("password="));
  Serial.println(password);
  Serial.print(F("operation="));
  Serial.println(operation);
  Serial.print(F("time="));
  Serial.println(time);
```